# Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

im making android app with jetpack compose and the code inside my MainActivity is like this:

So basically it is checking updates for the app before splash screen gone but the problem is when i turn my internet connection off and enter the app this error will happens and the user will jump out of app (And in the logs i see it keeps spamming this) :

```
--------- beginning of crash
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (2946) for package com.example.iranmcpe ----------------------------
2023-09-30 15:00:17.610  2577-2778  ActivityThread          pid-2577                             E  Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2023-09-30 15:00:25.296  2926-2978  Finsky                  pid-2926                             I  [134] vpd.h(7): Already at the latest configurations for experiment package com.google.android.finsky.regular.
2023-09-30 15:00:25.501  2926-3411  Finsky                  pid-2926                             I  [197] vpd.h(7): Already at the latest configurations for experiment package com.google.android.finsky.stable.
2023-09-30 15:00:27.934  2577-2778  ActivityThread          pid-2577                             E  Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2023-09-30 15:00:33.008  2577-2778  ActivityThread          pid-2577                             E  Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2023-09-30 15:00:38.056  2577-2778  ActivityThread          pid-2577                             E  Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2023-09-30 15:00:43.183  2577-2778  ActivityThread          pid-2577                             E  Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
```

here's also my gradle:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.000"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.000"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:compose:1.0.0-alpha.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.3")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

When i open the app with connected internet, it works fine witout problem but the only time i want open app with no internet connection, this crash will happen!

How to fix it? what is the problem?! Thanks in andvanced.